# Quickblox group dialog join not working on android

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

Here is my code...

```
mQbChatDialog.join(history, new QBEntityCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {

               Log.e("Sucess"," == Success");
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
               Log.e("Sucess"," == Success");
           }
       });
```

it is returning error.
**com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: XMPPError: internal-server-error - wait**

Please help.

Comment: Same here. starting 16-8-18. Android and iOS. ios: 2.17.1 android: 3.8.1.  (another post: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/624)

Comment: There are no answers :(

Comment: Actually, the error is gone now. Everything works for me again

Comment: Yes, same here :)